# C++/CLI How to return ArrayList^

Tags: c++-cli

```
ArrayList^ className::getAll() {
    ArrayList^ items = gcnew ArrayList;
    //More code...
```

return items;
}

This throws me:
c2143  error syntax missing ; before ^
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I'm using namespace System::Collection;

Comment: These are the errors you'll get when you **don't** have a `using namespace System::Collections;` in your code.  The code is otherwise correct, post a better snippet.  And use List<>.

Comment: @nobugz : There is also an offchance he doesn't have a reference to mscorlib...

Comment: `ArrayList` is there for backward-compatibility with pre-generics .NET only.  There have been better options for 6 years.  Don't use it in new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know the answer.I was using namespace System::Collections, but the problem was that I was adding it in StdAfx.h header (which is added in className.cpp). The namespace System::Collections must be **added in className.h, directly**. That worked very well.

Answer (score -1):

Change "^" to "*".

```
ArrayList* className::getAll() {
    ArrayList* items = new ArrayList();
    //More code...


    return items;
}
```

Comment: No, this is code in the C++/CLI language.  The hat is required.

Comment: Don't know much about C++ managed but saw this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(VS.71).aspx) in msdn which uses star instead of hat.  For my edification, what is the difference?

Comment: .NET 1.1 only supported the old syntax named "Managed C++".  Full of underscores, like __gc.  Change the version number on that MSDN page.

Comment: "Managed Extensions for C++" was VC++ 2002 and 2003's incarnation of managed C++, which was made up of normal C++ plus some extra keywords (notably, `__gc`). "C++/CLI" is VC++ 2005 and higher's incarnation of managed C++, which is an entirely different language than C++.